# Targeting iframe src from user input in javascript form

Tags: javascript, forms, url, iframe, src

I'm trying to target an iframe's source from a javascript form. So if someone typed in http://www.reddit.com the iframe's source would change to reddit.com 
I've tried a few things but you can't put a script tag within  src, so is there any way to do this with javascript, or would i need to make a php echo function?

```
<iframe  src="http://www.stachoverflow.com/"></iframe>
```

Comment: typed where? in address line of the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<input type="url" placeholder="http://example.com/" /><button id="urlclick">Go</button>
<iframe id="frm"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('urlclick').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('frm').src = this.previousSibling.value;
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using jquery we can do like this..

```
<input type="text" id="address">
<button onclick="get_url()"></button>
<iframe id="frm"></iframe>

<script>
function get_url()
{
var adr=$('#address').val();
$('#frm').attr('src', url);
}
</script>
```