# Using javascript/jquery, pass form variables to iframe src parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe

I have an iframe like this:

```
<iframe name="report-iframe" id="report-iframe" src="https://reporting.com/embed" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want to replace the src value using values from a form

```
<form method="post" target="report-iframe">
<input id="form-type" name="form-type" type="text" />
<input id="form-date" name="form-date" type="date" />
<input type="button" value="Update Report" onclick="javascript_function()"/>
</form>
```

so the resulting source of the iframe is:

```
src="https://reporting.com/embed?param_type=form-type&param_date=form-date"
```

Then reload the iframe with the passed parameters.

I want to do this using only javascript/jquery if possible.

Comment: We can't do that for you, but there is [already a topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14007726/411335) on this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jQuery approach.

```js
function javascript_function() {
  $('#report-iframe').attr('src','https://reporting.com/embed?param_type=' + $('#form-type').val() + '&param_date=' +  $('#form-date').val());    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe name="report-iframe" id="report-iframe" src="https://reporting.com/embed" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>


<form method="post" target="report-iframe">
<input id="form-type" name="form-type" type="text" />
<input id="form-date" name="form-date" type="date" />
<input type="button" value="Update Report" onclick="javascript_function()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72ux8kfg/8/) accomplishes what you're asking. You'll want to tweak it for robustness, but basically you can target the form (I used `$('form')` but for a real-world scenario you might want to be more specific.) and use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to turn its values into a query string, then append that to the src attribute of your iframe.

Edit: Note that for your specific example to work with `.serialize()`, you'd want the `name` attribute of #form-type to be "param_type" and the `name` attribute of #form-date to be "param_date"